# Per application rules in iptable

Tags: iptables

Is there possibility to add rule via iptable for specific process name?

Good explanation of why I need it is [here](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/399236-Controlling-outgoing-traffic-per-application):

> "Under Windows, this helps making the PC more secure. There are many applications that "phone home" over standard ports, i.e. send information about behavioral patterns of the user (e.g. Real Player, Adobe Acrobat Reader, WinAmp, etc.), or surf the internet for whatever it is they do. Many applications send information every time an application is started to the Microsoft registration server, generating a usage pattern. While most of this information is rather harmless, once in a while you encounter an application that sends data you would rather not have in the public.
>   It was always quite interesting to see what a newly installed application would want to send out to the internet. "

I googled that there WAS option `-m owner --cmd-owner`, but what to use now?
Or may by analogue of that option will be available in upcoming `nftables`?

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked many times.

The reason why what you suggest is not very useful is that, in Linux, this is done by different applications, (SELinux, AppArmor, SMACK,....), not via firewall. These applications ensure that the apps being monitored are completely isolated from the context, so they actually provide a much tighter control than just a firewall.

If however you need a quick and dirty application, such a thing exists, and is called [LeoPard Flower](http://leopardflower.sourceforge.net/).

Alternatively, you can do it as follows: run the app in a Linux container or a VM, for a few days, block all attempts to contact the Internet, and take a look at the log. This will help you identify whom they are trying to contact, and you may then block exactly those IPs.

I did this a few years ago, when I found out that even legitimate Web sites pointed to Mac OS images suitably modified *to be run in Linux VMs* (or so they claimed), given away for free. And I was curious to find out how nefarious they were. (The answer, unsurprisingly, was: **totally**).

Comment: So, you said to use something like apparmot, but here is what says apparmor manual:
AppArmor supports simple coarse grained network mediation.  The network rule restrict all socket(2) based operations.  The mediation done is a course grained check on whether a socket of a given type and family can be created, read, or written.  There is no mediation based of port number or protocol beyond tcp, udp, and raw.

Comment: And in addition, it seems that it is impossible to define some "default" profile which will be applied to all programmes except those ones, which explicitly have profile.
(And all described above, except binding to programme name I can do via iptables...)
If I am wrong, give me pls link to help/man

Comment: @Void The Ubuntu man page, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor#More_information, states: *AppArmor is a Mandatory Access Control (MAC) system which is a kernel (LSM) enhancement to confine programs to a limited set of resources. AppArmor's security model is to bind access control attributes to programs rather than to users.* This is exactly what you asked for. As for the default profile, you should read lines 1.4/1.5/1.6 of this document: http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/FAQ

Comment: Yes, but also it says
"There is no mediation based of port number"
so it is completely useless for described above use case (in short: allow http/https traffic for chrome and disallow for other apps) because I need to heavily use port numbers